# Unable to get Bold text using HTML to PDF converter from Select.Pdf

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, nuget, pdf-conversion

I'm trying to get my text bold in PDF.
I am using HTML to PDF converter from Select.Pdf (C#).
http://selectpdf.com/

I have included text style() in html but eventually it is not working.
I have also tried adding strong tag and b tag in HTML. But no success.

Kindly anybody save me!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would like to say. You should always try to provide us with some code.

My guess is that you might be using some unique fonts which don't support **BOLD** or *ITALIC* .

Please give it a try and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide me with some of the HTML that is not being converted correctly and a snippet of the C# logic being used so I can get a better understanding?

I was able to produce the desired result using the following:

```
SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf convertor = new SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf();
convertor.Options.PdfPageSize = SelectPdf.PdfPageSize.A4;
convertor.Options.PdfPageOrientation = SelectPdf.PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;

SelectPdf.PdfDocument doc = convertor.ConvertHtmlString("<strong>bold</strong> normal");
doc.Save("/Pdfs/test.pdf");
doc.Close();
```

[image: Example produced by above code]